# finding lower bound with given facts (relative error and relative residual)

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Given:

$A \in R^{n\times n}$

$x, \hat{x},r,b \in R^{n}, x \neq \hat{x}$

$r = b - A \hat{x}$

1) $\|x - \hat{x}\| \le \|A^{-1}\| \,\|r\|$

2) $\|b\| \le \|A\| \, \|x\|$

How do I reach this conclusion (lowerbound):

$\frac{1}{\|A\| \, \|A^{-1}\|}\frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|} \le \frac{\|x-\hat{x}\|}{\|x\|}$

The proof of upperbound was shown as an example:

$\frac{\|x- \hat{x}\|}{\|A\| \, \|x\|} \le \frac{\|A^{-1}\| \,\|r\|}{\|b\|}$

$\implies \frac{\|x - \hat{x}\|}{\|x\|} \le \|A\| \, \|A^{-1}\| \, \frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|}$

The proof for lowerbound was skipped, it just said "Similar argument leads to ...". but I'm lost on how to apply a similar argument for the lower bound :(

Comment: $ \frac{1}{||A|| \, ||A^{-1}||}\frac{||r||}{||b||}  \le \frac{||x - \hat{x}||}{||x||} \le ||A|| \, ||A^{-1}|| \, \frac{||r||}{||b||}$  wouldn't both bounds combined be this, is there something wrong here?

Comment: My apologies, I haven't had enough wine yet. Sounds of deleting.

Comment: haha no worries

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me, if one chooses $\hat{x} = x$, then there is no reason why we must have $r = 0$. So, I still think something is missing (my wine bottle is empty).

Comment: yea sorry $\hat{x}$ is a slightly perturbed $x$, edited to make it clear

Comment: You need more, if it is true for all $\hat{x} \ne x$ close to $x$, then you must have $r=0$.

Comment: Is $r=Ax-b$ perhaps?

Comment: $r = b - A \hat{x}$

Comment: $x$ is the exact solution, $Ax=b$. Then $r=b-A\hat x=A(x-\hat x)$ and thus $\|r\|\le\|A\|·\|x-\hat x\|$. Combine with $\|x\|=\|A^{-1}b\|\le\|A^{-1}\|·\|b\|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you used $b=Ax$ and $x-\hat x=A^{-1}b$ to conclude
$$
\|x-\hat x\|·\|b\|\le \|A\|·\|x\|·\|A^{-1}\|·\|r\|\implies
\frac{\|x-\hat x\|}{\|x\|}\le \|A\|·\|A^{-1}\|·\frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|}
$$
you can conversely start with
$x=A^{-1}b$ and $r = b-A\hat x=A(x-\hat x)$ to conclude
$$
\|x\|·\|b\|\le\|A^{-1}\|·\|b\|·\|A\|·\|x-\hat x\|\implies
\frac1{\|A\|·\|A^{-1}\|}·\frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|}\le\frac{\|x-\hat x\|}{\|x\|}
$$